# Online multiplayer game using Google Play Games Services in Cocos2D-X

Tags: cocos2d-x, google-play-games, multiplayer

We are developing an **online cross-platform turn-based multiplayer game**. We are thinking of using **Google Play Games Service plug-in available in Cocos2D-X**. For integration of this plug-in into our game, we need to use **SDKBOX**.

I have the following queries:

1. Has anyone had experience (good or bad) working with **SDKBOX and Google Play Game Services**?
2. Does SDKBOX **communicate** with SDKBOX servers? If so, does this mean that they could start charging in the future based on your game's usage of that server?
3. How good is the **matchmaking feature** in Google Play Game Services?

I'd appreciate any suggestions on these queries. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked a lot with SDKBOX in the past, not with GPG but with other plugins and in the long run I ended up having two problems:

1. Cocos2d-x update: when you import an sdkbox plugin it makes changes into the cocos folder so updating cocos will be a problem because you will have to manually redo all the changes that sdkbox does into the cocos folder.
2. GPG update: sometimes it happens that Google will push some vital changes to GPG and sdkbox will be obsolete until update and because sdkbox is closed source you will have to wait until they release an update.

Their products work great for people who are not that technical but I would suggest to create your own native GPG implementation and create an JNI bridge to communicate between c++ and java. This way it will be easier to debug and update.

There are many tutorials online on how to install and configure GPG in your android app and creating an JNI bridge is not that hard. In the long run it will be more beneficial for your game not having to depend on external plugins.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It will be helpful if you can provide more information about SDKBOX. Does SDKBOX communicate with SDKBOX servers? If so, does this mean they could start charging in the future based on game's usage of that server?

Comment: I don't think SDKBOX communicates with their servers because SDKBOX is just a bridge between c++ and native targets, all GPG data it's comming from Google servers.

Comment: Thank you. I also think the same. As per the privacy policy of SDKBOX, they only store details of developer with package name, bundle id etc of the game. Can you suggest better plugins for multiplayer implementation with good matchmaking APIs other than GPG?

Comment: There are other solution than GPG for multiplayer like: https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Photon , http://www.smartfoxserver.com/ , http://appwarp.shephertz.com/ , https://aws.amazon.com/gaming/... I haven't worked with any of them. Firebase might be a solution if you want to create your own stuff.

Comment: Regarding GPG update and SDKBOX becoming obsolete, would that only be problem during development or could it break our game after its been released?

Comment: It might happen or it might never happen but its a possibility you have to consider. Keep in mind that unlike cocos2dx, sdkbox is not open source and you cannot alter it's code, so doing it by yourself you will have control over the code and can update any time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.